# Problemas com include de arquivos, apontantando diretório em relação a pagina que foi aberta primeiro

Tags: php

Estou com problema quando meu projeto possui uma estrutura com porfundidade grande de diretórios. Quando dou include no arquivo a url fica relativo a pagina que foi aberta. E daí em alguns arquivos os *includes* não são reconhecidos.

Por exemplo abro uma pagina com profundidade 3 de diretorio, dou *include* em um arquivo com profundidade 2, e dentro desse arquivo os includes que ele possuem passam a não reconhcer os arquivos pois a url está em relação à primeira página que abri.

sem contar que muitos arquivos preciso fazer isso `../../../arquivo.php` para reconhcer arquivos de outros diretórios.

**ESTRUTURA EXEMPLO**

```
.
├── controller
│   └── entityController.class.php
│
│
├── model
│   └── entity.class.php
│   
|
└── ws
    ├── dir
    │   └── page1.php
    └── dir2
        └── page2.php
```

**SITUAÇÃO**

**1º** page1 é aberta nela possui um include a entityController.class.php a dois niveis acima para poder acessar

`include '../../controller/entityController.class.php';`

**2º** entityController possui um include a entity que precisa voltar a um nivel acima para poder acessar

`include '../model/entity.class.php';`

Pronto ai surge o problema, esse include não funciona pois ocorre em relação ao nivel do arquivo page1.php que foi o primeiro a ser chamado, logo ele vai procurar a pasta `model` dentro do diretorio `ws`, ou seja para dar certo teria que fazer assim

`include '../../model/entity.class.php';`

Mas resolveria nesse caso, e ja seria problema pois o controller é chamado por outros arquivos de diferentes niveis.

Comment: no arquivo que faz a chamado ao include, apenas precisa saber a própria base. Para isso, apenas faça algo do tipo $base = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

Comment: Esse espaço para comentario é muito limitado.. onde está  dirname(FILE) é  dirname(_ _ FILE _ _) remova os espaços dentro do parênteses...

Comment: outra opção é o realpath('.').. mas não recomendo o uso pois pode retornar um caminho diferente quando executado via command line/shell.

Comment: @DanielOmine Seu comentário já é a solução do problema dele. Passe para uma resposta que fica mais legível e ele pode marcar como aceita.

Comment: Eu sei André Ribeiro, mas não tenho saco de ficar escrevendo uma resposta megalomaníaca.. E se eu postar algo simples, prático e objetivo, vai aparecer uns "***" para dar negativo.. rsrsr espero que entenda.. Quem tiver disposição, mãos a  obra!

Comment: Eu já tentei utilizar dirname( _ _FILE_ _ ), e até _ _ DIR _ _ , mas não funcionou tbm, pois isso esta mostrando a url completa do primeiro arquivo que foi aberto, e acontece isso `...../ws/dir/controller/entityController.class.php`.

Comment: usei `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` e deu certo, vou fazer alguns testes.

Comment: @Juarez considere postar uma resposta explicando como usou o DOCUMENT_ROOT, assim outros visitantes com problema similar podem aproveitar sua solução (que no meu ver, é a mais correta, pois independe de onde você está dando o include - apesar de o título da sua pergunta sugerir caminho relativo)

Comment: Eu iria postar a resposta mas o @KaduAmaral ja havia respondido com clareza como funciona o `__DIR__` então não achei justo postar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que for colocar um *include* ou *require* utilize o caminho absoluto, invés de caminho relativo, isso é bem fácil usando as constantes "mágicas". Experimente assim:

pager1

```
include __DIR__.'/../../controller/entityController.class.php'
```

entityController

```
include __DIR__.'/../model/entity.class.php';
```

Note que a constante `__DIR__` não possui a última barra, fazendo-se necessário coloca-la.

A constante `__DIR__` retorna o nome do diretório do arquivo atual (o arquivo que está utilizando-a) o mesmo que `dirname( __FILE__ )`.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado, estava usando de forma incorreta, não estava usando `/../` após a concatenação, não sabia que poderia funcionar dessa forma, outro método que achei que funcinou foi utilizar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/model/entity.class.php`  daí nao precisa passar parametros de voltar `/../`. É uma coisa tão simples eu ja sabia, mas não achei um lugar que explicasse como utilizar. Agora não vou ter dúvidas em como funciona.

Comment: Então @Juarez, eu nunca utilizei esse `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, acabei de aprender algo com tua pergunta, rsrs. Valeu!